# Controlling Select2 programmatically without jQuery

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jquery-select2, e2e-testing

How to control [select2](/questions/tagged/select2) component programmatically **without** jQuery? The code is going to be executed using Selenium and since I don't have access to the jQuery object (it's bundled with Webpack), it has to be controlled using pure JS.

I tried simulating user click like this:

```
document.getElementById('select2').click()
```

but it doesn't open. What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. open Select2
2. type something inside its search box to trigger the ajax call and shows possible options
3. select an option by text

Answer (score 0):

You can try this workaround: `document.querySelector("#example + span > .selection > span")` and then trigger click. Fiddle to check: https://jsfiddle.net/zeLbk6s3/2/

You have to trigger "click" on proper element.

Comment: Tried to open the Select2 on https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax using browser console with `document.querySelector('.selection > span').click()` and this fails to open the component.